# Unable to view the page after logged in

Tags: php, mysql

when I go to the page that I put the authentication code it will ask me to log in first before login. The issues are after I logged in it doesn't go to the page that wanted to go and after that clicked to the same page again it ask me to log in again. Am I did something wrong here!?

loginform.php

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <di class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login </legend>
            <form method="post" action="loginProcess.php">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label>User name:</label>
               <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
            </div>
            </form>
            </fieldset>
    </di>
</div>
```

loginProcess.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("dbCon.php");


    $username = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'username') ? $_POST['username']: null;
    $passWD  = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'password') ? $_POST['password']: null;

        $sql = "SELECT passwordHash FROM te_users WHERE username = ?"; 
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);    

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);  
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $passWDHash); //Get the password hash from the query results for the given username and store it in the variable indicated

        if(!empty($username)){
            if(!empty($passWD)){
                if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) { //Check if a record was returned by the query.
                    if (password_verify($passWD,$passWDHash)){
                        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
                        $login = $_SESSION['login'];
                        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                        header("location:index.php");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<p>Sorry, we don't seem to have that password.</p>";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo "<p>Sorry, we don't seem to have that username.</p>";
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "<p>Please enter the password.</p>";
            }   
        }
        else {
            echo "<p>Please enter the username.</p>";
        }   


    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 
    mysqli_close($conn); 

?>
```

otherpage.php

this is the code that use for authentication

```
if( empty($_SESSION['logged_in']) )
{
     header('Location:login.php');
        exit;
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: start the session everywhere

Comment: and there's a typo here `</di>`

Comment: ...and yet another typo `<di class...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing things the wrong way round in the section that registers the successful login, and also setting a different `$SESSION` variable name than the one you check in your *are they logged in code*.

```
                if (password_verify($passWD,$passWDHash)){

                    //$username = $_SESSION['username'];
                    //$login = $_SESSION['login'];
                    //$_SESSION['login'] = true;

                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

                    header("location:index.php");
                } else {
                    echo "<p>Sorry, we don't seem to have that password.</p>";
                }
```

Also remember to start the session in any script that want to use the session

```
<?php
session_start();

if( empty($_SESSION['logged_in']) ) {
    header('Location:login.php');
    exit;
} else {

}
```

Comment: _It does not work_ Is not very much help. What are the probelms now?

Comment: @Sith1234Sith Did you fix the `<di>` and `</di>` bugs

Comment: It worked. I replaced the authenticate code or the 2nd  code it works!! thank you